# CsvReporter not spitting out metrics in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, metrics

I have added the following file on my cassandra node

/etc/dse/cassandra/metrics-reporter-config.yaml

```
csv:
  -
    outdir: '/mnt/cassandra/metrics'
    period: 10
    timeunit: 'SECONDS'
    predicate:
      color: "white"
      useQualifiedName: true
      patterns:
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Cache.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.CommitLog.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Compaction.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.DroppedMetrics.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ReadRepair.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Storage.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ThreadPools.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ColumnFamily.+"
        - "^org.apache.cassandra.metrics.Streaming.+"
```

And then added this line to etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh

```
 ​JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile=metrics-reporter-config.yam"
```

And then finally restarted DSE, /etc/init.d/dse restart

I dont see any csv metrics files being spitted out by the MetricsReported in /mnt/cassandra/metrics folder.

any  ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs, check if you have something like:

`Trying to load metrics-reporter-config from file` followed by `Enabling CsvReporter to`

Possibly metrics reporter could not create metrics directory or so...

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just had to change `csv:` to `console:`